# how to set value in text area

Tags: php, textarea

I'm working on the playground using from codemirror.net, and is works great. My next step is to have auto load set a value to file path name, each textarea will load file path from .html, .css and jquery.

currently in codemirror showing

```
<div id="wrap">

  <!-- Code Editors -->   <section id="code_editors">
    <div id="html" class="code_box">
      <h3>HTML</h3>
      <textarea name="html"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="css" class="code_box">
      <h3>CSS</h3>
      <textarea name="css"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="js" class="code_box">
      <h3>JavaScript</h3>
      <textarea name="js"></textarea>
    </div>   </section>
     <!-- Sandboxing -->   <section id="output">
    <iframe></iframe>   </section>    </div>
```

The result of preview textarea showed "Hello world" that because in javascript showed

```
  html_editor.setValue('<p>Hello World</p>');
    css_editor.setValue('body { color: red; }');
```

so i change set value in codemirror like this.

```
    <textarea name="html"><?php
echo file_get_contents('testcode.php');
?>
</textarea>
</div>
```

this works great when I see HTML code inside of text area but unable to see the preview in the text area.

so I'm trying to solve this how to see preview too using

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('testcode.php');?>
```

I thought to make change in javascript where it said

```
html_editor.setValue('<p>Hello World</p>');
    css_editor.setValue('body { color: red; }');
```

my question is that how can I write code in PHP inside of javascript file.

i tried

```
html_editor.setValue('<?php echo file_get_contents('testcode.php');?>');
    css_editor.setValue('body { color: red; }');
```

it does not work.

Any other idea how to solve this to make both works!

many thanks.

AM

Comment: PHP is normally only parsed when the file name ends with `.php` You could set your server to parse .js files for PHP, but why not simply use a .php file that prints javascripT?  <script source="jscript.php" . . .

Comment: I never thought about the prints javascript, so how to write to print in javascript is like this  <script source="<?php echo file_get_contents('testcode.php');?></script> is this correct!

Comment: No, just <script source="jscript.php"> </script>  You can copy your current js file into the new .php file THEN you can use `<?=$var?>` or `<?php echo $var;?>` to print PHP variables where you need.. Just like you can mix PHP and HTML, you can also mix JS and PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
var = "<?php echo file_get_contents('testcode.php')?>";
html_editor.setValue(var );
css_editor.setValue('body { color: red; }');
```

Comment: i have tried  and is not working,what it does is print "var"... I tried other way not working... any idea! please!

Comment: Can u show me the screenshot of testcode.php page ?

Comment: please see in [link]https://jsfiddle.net/Alidad3250/rqd30fro/3/ please see in javascript section line number 89 to 91 and i comment out sample copy line is 94 to 96